# What conditions need to be fulfilled for a window message to be posted?

Tags: winapi, window-messages

I've successfully registered a window class using `RegisterClassEx` and created a window using `CreateWindowEx`:

```
m_hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
...
m_hWnd = ::CreateWindowEx(0, "CMyClassName", "Message Window", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, m_hInstance, 0);
```

The associated window procedure receives messages 36, 129, 131, and 1, and the returned `HWND` is not null.  However, when I later call `PostMessage` (from another thread):

```
bool bPosted = ::PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_APP + 3, 0, 0);
```

even though bPosted is true, the window procedure isn't called.  I'm trying to work out why that should be.  The window procedure is the one from the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28VS.85%29.aspx) - I'd intented to add another case once I'd confirmed the messages were getting through.

What conditions need to be fulfilled for a window message to be posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conditions.

Some constraints exist when using messages [0, WM_USER) but none over WM_APP.

Are you checking the return code of [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx)?

You should probably post (at least some of) the code you're using to PostMessage, as well as the registered WndProc.

You also have to provide a [message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928(VS.85).aspx#creating_loop), if you are not doing so.  Most frameworks will hide this detail (at least somewhat), but if you're dealing with win32 directly you have to provide your own.

Comment: The WndProc is probably important here.  I guess the message loop as well, if just for completeness.

Comment: I've added a link to the wndproc code I used.  Do I need to write a message loop?  I already received the four messages I described, so I assumed there was a message loop running.

Comment: Not knowing the details of the rest of your code, maybe.  Its pretty basic boilerplate so it shouldn't be too rough to just try it.  I've added a link to a relevant MSDN article.

Comment: Yep, it was the message loop that I lacked.  Thanks!